# Number of ways to fill boxes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $n<10$ and $m\geq n+1.\ $
You are given $m$ boxes and you have to fill those boxes with all the numbers (numbers can b repeat when $m>n+1$ and if $m=n+1$ then all n+1 numbers are to be used  )from $0$ to $n$ 
such that absolute difference between adjacent boxes is $1$.

Find an expression for $T$, the total number of different ways of filling the $m$ boxes with $n$ numbers, in terms of $n$ and $m$.

I could only find: when $m$ is equal to $n+1$, the number of ways is $2$.
But i have no idea for general case. Can any one please help me?

Comment: Can you repeat numbers? (for example, $0, 1, 0, 1, 2, \dots$)

Comment: If you can repeat numbers then I think it's just $2^m$

Comment: do empty boxes count as 0 ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?   You speak of the case $m=n$, but did you mean $m=n+1$?  With $m=n=2$, say, you'd have the three numbers $0,1,2$ to fit into two boxes so you could have $(0,1), (1,0), (1,2), (2,1)$, unless I am misunderstanding.  Please edit your post for clarity.  Including a few examples might help.

Comment: lulu: I interpreted it as, e.g. if n = m = 9, we could have:

(0,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,4).

OP didn't specify in the question if we had to use *all* the numbers from 0 to n. They just said " with numbers". So you could also do (0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0).

Comment: I have corrected the question

Comment: "Numbers can **b** repeat when $m>n+1$"  That still does not fully clarify... Okay, so numbers can be repeated... but for $m=n+1$ all $n+1$ numbers are used?  For $m>n+1$ must every number be used at least once?  Otherwise it seems silly that $(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots,1,0)$ is allowable for $m>n+1$ while not allowed for $m=n+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $m \gt n$ you must be allowed to repeat numbers.  This answer assumes that you are not required to use all the numbers.  You say you have to when $m=n+1$, but what about if $m$ is greater yet?

I would write a recurrence.  Once you choose the first number the sequence is defined by $m-1$ choices of up or down, one for each succeeding number.  For fixed $n$, define $T(k,m)$ as the number of $m$ number sequences ending with $k$.  You get a system of recurrences
$$T(k,m)=\begin {cases}T(1,m-1)&k=0\\
T(n-1,m-1)&k=n\\
T(k-1,m-1)+T(k+1,m-1)&1\le k \le n-1 \end {cases}$$
With starting condition $T(k,1)=1$ for all $k$.  This is a tridiagonal matrix, which you can diagonalize and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

For example, for $n=4$ the [eigenvalues](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvector%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Eigenvector%22%2C%20%22eigvecmatrix%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D%22) are $\pm \sqrt 3, \pm 1, 0$ so the number will grow essentially as $\sqrt{3^m}$.    The eigenvectors have a nice structure so that you can represent the starting vector easily.

Comment: Assuming every number must be used at least once (*implied by how every number must be used exactly once for the case of $m=n+1$*), I don't see how this approach accounts for that.

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I did not assume that as it wasn't there when I answered.  I will put that into the answer.  Thanks.